# Camel log component with log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, log4j2

I have a `spring-boot` application with `apache camel` and `log4j2` as the underlying log provider. Is it possible to use camel log component to write to the log files as configured by the `log4j2.xml`?
Below jar files are there in the classpath:-

```
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
logback-classic-1.1.5.jar
logback-core-1.1.5.jar
log4j-api-2.4.1.jar
log4j-core-2.4.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently have two logger implementations configured: Log4j 2 and Logback. If you want to do all your logging with Log4j2 then you need to add the Log4j SLF4J bridge and remove the Logback jars. I also recommend you use the latest Log4j 2 version (2.6.1). That gives the following dependencies:

- log4j-api-2.6.1.jar
- log4j-core-2.6.1.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.1.jar (routes SLF4J API calls to Log4j 2)
- log4j-jcl-2.6.1.jar (routes Commons Logging API calls to Log4j 2)
- log4j-jul-2.6.1.jar (also set system property `java.util.logging.manager` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`)
- slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar

You don't need:

```
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
logback-classic-1.1.5.jar
logback-core-1.1.5.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar
```

About configuration, by default Log4j2 looks for a file called log4j2.xml in the classpath, but you can also [specify the location](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location) with a system property.

The Log4j 2 [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) is much better than the Log4j 1 documentation and shows many [example configurations](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).

Comment: Was this answer useful?